# Private installation/update of TikZ in Linux

Tags: tikz-pgf, installing, updating, tikzlibrary

I'd like to make a private installation in Linux of (part of) TikZ, in order to be able to `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}` (note that I cannot update my TeX distrubution, which has already a basic version of TikZ).

I know some info is [here](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-privinst), but I'd like a simple string of shell commands; also I'd like to know how much space this would take.

Up to now, I've done `mkdir ~/texmf`.

Comment: You download pgf cvs here : http://pgf.sourceforge.net/pgf_CVS.tds.zip then you add the folders doc and tex in `~/texmf`

Comment: @PaulGessler it's always interesting to use this method because in  the next months a cvs version will be developed

Comment: @AlainMatthes That's a useful method but I'm not sure it is appropriate here. The OP wants to use `decorations.markings`. That is available at least in TeX Live 2011. So there isn't really any reason to think the OP wants the cutting edge version, is there? It sounds more like the OP has a small TeX installation which includes only a subset of PGF/TiKZ.

Answer (score 2):

CW from the comments:

The bleeding-edge development version of TikZ/`pgf` is available from [Sourceforge](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/) ([direct `.zip` download link](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/pgf_CVS.tds.zip)). This is a TDS-compliant archive that can be unzipped in your system's `TEXMFHOME` directory (usually `~/texmf`: find it for certain using `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` on the terminal).

Once placed here, all features (and bugs/regressions!) of the development version will be available on your system.